# Calendar in PrimeFaces, time and localization

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Welcome. I wanted to add the calendar with PrimeFaces on my website. I want to use the TimePicker to also be able to set the time. So looks like my calendar:

```
<p:calendar value="#{visitMB.visit.dateVisit}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" locale="tr" navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true" mode="inline" mindate="now"/>
```

When I set the pattern: `dd-MM-yyyy` without the time everything is added correctly, but when I change to: `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` I get this error:

> j_idt10:j_idt12: '19-06-2013' could not be understood as a date and
>   time.

This is when I set the inline mode, when I set the popup is all ok.

I have a problem with the localization my calendar.

I create the file polski.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
PrimeFaces.locales['pl'] = {
    closeText: 'Zamknij',
    prevText: 'Poprzedni',
    nextText: 'Następny',
    monthNames: ['Styczeń','Luty','Marzec','Kwiecień','Maj','Czerwiec','Lipiec','Sierpień','Wrzesień','Październik','Listopad','Grudzień'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Sty','Lut','Mar','Kwi','Maj','Cze', 'Lip','Sie','Wrz','Paź','Lis','Gru'],
    dayNames: ['Niedziela','Poniedziałek','Wtorek','Środa','Czwartek','Piątek','Sobota'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Nie','Pon','Wt','Śr','Czw','Pt','So'],
    dayNamesMin: ['N','P','W','Ś','Cz','P','S'],
    weekHeader: 'Tydzień',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: 'r',
    timeOnlyTitle: 'Tylko czas',
    timeText: 'Czas',
    hourText: 'Godzina',
    minuteText: 'Minuta',
    secondText: 'Sekunda',
    currentText: 'Teraz',
    ampm: false,
    month: 'Miesiąc',
    week: 'Tydzień',
    day: 'Dzień',
    allDayText : 'Cały dzień'
};
</script>
```

and in my page i added:

```
        <h:outputScript name="C:\Users\Piotr\Desktop\polski.js" />
        <p:calendar value="#{visitMB.visit.dateVisit}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" locale="pl" navigator="true"  mode="inline" mindate="now"/>
```

But localization don't work. Why?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in that component, you can find similar reports if you search for it (i.e. http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22674). You cannot user time picker in inline mode.

Comment: It's bug on PrimeFaces.

Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036356/bug-in-primefaces-calendar-timepicker/23037478